# print text of file to console using Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

New to Node.js. 
running on MacOS 
Here is my code within a textEdit document... File is called cctest.js ... and the file i am trying to read is cc1.txt which is a textEdit document as well. Both of these files are in the same working directory. i call node cctest.js in terminal. the code below is contained in the cctest.js file. 
i have tried numerous peoples solutions and some walkthrough videos all with the same result rejecting my var fs = require("fs") or rejecting the fs.readFile() line

```
var fs = require(“fs”);

var fileToRead = ‘cc1.txt’;

fs.readFile(fileToRead, ‘utf8’, (err, data) => {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
} else {
    console.log(data);
}
});
```

here is my error message.

```
var fs = require(“fs”);

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Comment: Have you tried using import statement, or with single quotes like that:

var fs = require('fs');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use non-curly quotes in JavaScript

```
var fs = require("fs");

var fileToRead = 'cc1.txt';

fs.readFile(fileToRead, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
} else {
    console.log(data);
}
});
```

Comment: much thanks man this worked right away. i copy and pasted your answer and it worked. but. i see that when i backspace your single quote and type my own it turns into the curled one... strange

Comment: yep had to go into keyboard settings and turn off the curly quotes. for anyone else who encounters this on mac OS.    Under System Preferences > Keyboard, you can change the quotation marks.
Go to the 'Text' sub-menu. On the right-hand side of the box, uncheck the "Use smart quotes and dashes" checkbox.

Comment: That should already be the default, make sure you're in plain text mode.

Answer (score 0):

You are using some sort of different quotation marks in your code `“` and backticks (left of number 1).

You should be using the standard quotations, single or double `'` `"`

```js
var fs = require('fs');

var fileToRead = 'cc1.txt';

fs.readFile(fileToRead, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    } else {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

If you are not able to use the standard quotes, there must be an issue with your keyboard settings.

In Windows you can do this  by going to your Time and Language settings

[image]

[image]

And change to a more standard keyboard.

Comment: yea i am trying to figure out how to get the straight quotes, for some reason mine are curled. much thanks for your help! i have been stuck on this one for a while

Comment: @NormanDavis Yep, I think its something to do with your keyboard settings. Change it to a Standard one and check if its working. I added windows related settings to change keyboards in my  answer, hope it helps

Comment: yep, thanks guys, went into keyboard settings got it straight

Answer (score -1):

Change your `“` char with `"`.
if still not working, try to `npm install fs`

Comment: The first line of this is a copy/paste of a line from the question, including the problems with it. The second line is not a coherent sentence. I've no idea what you are trying to say.

Comment: Re edit: `fs` is a built-in module. It can't be installed via NPM.

Comment: i apologize for the poor grammar just trying to explain in detail my situation.